# Htaccess redirect allways to index except if specific subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have this task, where I have to make basically two webpages under one domain. Main page always have to go through `index.php`. Except if / subdirectory (under subdirectory there is another webpage) - then works with subdirectory

**Example:**

- example.com  -> goes to index.php
- example.com/subdirectory ->goes to /subdirectory/index.php
- example.com/subdirectory/peter -> goes to /subdirectory/peter/
- example.com/example2 -> goes to index.php

**This is what I have managed so far:**

```
    #If 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdirectory/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # rewrite
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forums/$1 [L]
    # IF
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # rewrite
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php [L]
```

Honestly I am out of ideas...

Found out how to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forums
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

atleast for now its workin.

Comment: The `!-f` and `!-d` will make it so the redirect will only happen if the requested file doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, the default settings for apache will have htaccess files in child directories overwrite the settings in parent directories. So you could also put a `.htaccess` in the sub directory that has it's own rules or even turns off url rewrite.

Comment: thanks guys. i found out how to do it.